# complex polynomials problem with a weird inequality

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that if $P(z) = a_nz^n+a_{n-1}z^{n-1}+...+a_1z + a_0$

is a polynomial of degree n then there is $R_0>0$ such that for $|z| > R_0$ the polynomial can be bound from below as

$|P(z)| > \frac{1}{2}|a_n||z|^n$

but what if you have the polynomial $P(z) = a_1z+a_0$ where $a_1 = -100$ and $a_0 = 100$ and we fill in $z = 1$ then we have the left side equal to $0$ and the right side equal to 50 so it does not hold. How does that work?

I also do not understand what the $R_0$ adds to the problem. Do i use it somewhere in the proof because i do not see its relevance otherwise than stating that absolute value is bigger than 0 also.

Comment: What you’ve shown for the case $100z-100$ is that $R_0\geq1.$

Comment: i said $a_1$ equal to -100 not 100 and my question first what was wrong because then you have 0>50 which is not true ofcourse so what do i do wrong?

Comment: But the statement doesn’t say $|f(z)|>\frac12|a_nz^n|$ for all $z$, only for $|z|>R_0.$ So the fact that the inequality doesn’t work for $z=1$ only means that you need to choose an $R_0$ so that it is not true that  $|1|>R_0.$

Answer (score 1):

The loose idea is that the lower bound applies when $|z|$ is "large enough".

The role of $R_0$ in the problem, which you asked about - "I also do not understand what the $R_0$ adds to the problem" - is to give a precise measure of what the vague phrase "large enough" means, in this context.

As has been pointed out in the comments, you needn't worry about what happens when $R_0$ is "small". You're perfectly at liberty to make $R_0$ as "large" as you like.

As your example illustrates, it is sometimes necessary to take $R_0 \geqslant 1$.

I just want to point out that if you make the assumption $R_0 \geqslant 1$ in the general case, it is easy to work out an exact value for $R_0$ that is good enough to do the job.

You don't *have* to do this. The problem doesn't ask you to name a particular value of $R_0$. As in Marios Gretsas's answer - in my opinion it is the "right" answer, but I wanted to add an observation - it enough to apply general theorems about limits to show that *some* value of $R_0$ exists.

I think that's what you should take away from this question, but at the risk of merely distracting you, here is a concrete way to make $|z|$ "large" enough:

Because $P$ is of degree $n,$ we have $a_n \ne 0$.

Let $A = |a_{n-1}| + \cdots + |a_1| + |a_0| \geqslant 0$.

For all $z \ne 0,$ write:
\begin{align*}
\frac{P(z)}{a_nz^n} & = \frac{a_nz^n + a_{n-1}z^{n-1} + \cdots + a_1z + a_0}{a_nz^n} \\
& = 1 + \frac{a_{n-1}}{a_nz} + \cdots + \frac{a_1}{a_nz^{n-1}} + \frac{a_0}{a_nz^n}.
\end{align*}
If $R_0 \geqslant 1$, then for all $z$ such that $|z| > R_0,$ we have $|z|^m > R_0^m \geqslant R_0 \quad (m = 1, 2, \ldots),$ therefore:
\begin{align*}
\frac{|P(z)|}{|a_n||z|^n} = \left\lvert\frac{P(z)}{a_nz^n}\right\rvert
& \geqslant 1 - \frac{|a_{n-1}|}{|a_n||z|} - \cdots - \frac{|a_1|}{|a_n||z|^{n-1}} - \frac{a_0}{|a_n||z|^n} \\
& \geqslant 1 - \frac{A}{|a_n|R_0} \\
& > \frac12 \quad \text{if } R_0 > \frac{2A}{|a_n|}.
\end{align*}
So it is good enough to define:
$$
R_0 = 1 + \frac{2A}{|a_n|}.
$$
In particular, for your example ($n = 1$), you could take:
$$
R_0 = 1 + \frac{2|a_0|}{|a_1|}.
$$

Comment: I appreciate this proof since it helps me to see what we're doing in this theorem.  We're trying to show that eventually every polynomial grows at least as fast as its leading term.

Answer (score 0):

We have that $\lim_{z \to \infty}\frac{|p(z)|}{|a_n||z|^n}=1$

So for $\epsilon=\frac{1}{2}$ exists $R_0>0$ such that $$\frac{|p(z)|}{|a_n||z|^n}>1-\epsilon=\frac{1}{2},\forall z:|z|>R_0$$

Comment: where do you get the $\epsilon- \frac{1}{2}$ from? and what does this inequality help me?

Comment: @Danielvanheuven i meant to write $\epsilon=1/2$...i edited..for that $\epsilon$ you apply the definition of limit at infinity..then you multiply both sides with $|a_n||z|^n$ and you have the desired conclusion

Comment: @Gretsas The definition of a limit has smaller than espsilon you have bigger than how does that work

Comment: And the limit definition says for all epsilon not just for epsilon is 1/2

Comment: @Danielvanheuven i know..but here you only need $\epsilon=1/2$ not all $\epsilon$